# Convert portable msysGit to full installed equivalent (but still be portable)

Tags: git, msysgit, portable-applications

Being a fan of portable apps (even when running on my primary workstation), I use the portable version of *msysGit*, however, it does not install the shell hooks, environment variables, GUI setup, icons etc. I would like to keep my `C:\` and installed apps to the original clean image provided by my employer so that whenever they provide a new Windows image, I don't have to reinstall all the portable apps (including Git).

Is there any script available that allows the portable version to simply be "registered" with the shell hooks (Git Bash Here / Git GUI here) and icons (but not installed)?

To ask another way, if I install the full version to say, `D:\PortableApps\Git`, would it be functionally equivalent to the portable version in terms of centralizing all file storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cut-n-paste the following in a file (say install.reg) and double-click it.

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\git_gui]
>   @="Git &GUI Here"
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\git_gui\command]
>   @="\"D:\PortableApps\Git\bin\wish.exe\" \"D:\PortableApps\Git\libexec\git-core\git-gui\"
>   \"--working-dir\" \"%1\""
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\git_shell]
>   @="Git Ba&sh Here"
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\git_shell\command]
>   @="wscript \"D:\PortableApps\Git\Git
>   Bash.vbs\" \"%1\""

Create a shortcut named Git Bash.lnk with the following target:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c
>   ""D:\PortableApps\Git\bin\sh.exe"
>   --login -i"

Your portable Git is now registered with the Windows shell.

Answer (score 1):

My MsysGit was installed in directory "f:\git177".
so my githere.reg file in windows 2003sp2 is :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git_gui]
@="Git &GUI Here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git_gui\command]
@="f:\\Git177\\bin\\wish.exe \"f:\\Git177\\libexec\\git-core\\git-gui\" \"--working-dir\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git_shell]
@="Git Ba&sh Here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git_shell\command]
@="wscript \"f:\\git177\\Git Bash.vbs\" \"%1\""
```